# Apt-get problems after installing Maya 2017

Tags: command-line, apt, dpkg

So I was working on trying to get Maya 2017 working the other day and in the process I must have done something wrong because now whenever I run ANY apt-get install command in terminal it tries to install maya or something also.

Here is an example where I try to install UMLet:

```
zach@zach-desktop:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install umlet
[sudo] password for zach: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
umlet is already the newest version (13.3-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
attr libaio1 libenca0 libldb1 libtalloc2 libtevent0 libvorbisidec1        libwbclient0 linux-headers-4.4.0-28 linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic linux-     headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic 
linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic mplayer-skins python-crypto python-dnspython python-ldb python-talloc
python-tdb tdb-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up maya2017-64 (2017.0-1721) ...
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/R12/lib64:
./adlmreg -ih S 01GH1 657H1 2016.0.0.F 000-00000000 /var/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/Maya2017/MayaConfig.pit
./adlmreg -ih N 01GH1 657H1 2016.0.0.F 000-00000000 /var/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/Maya2017/MayaConfig.pit
libadlmutil.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directorylibadlmutil.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directorydpkg: error processing package maya2017-64 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
maya2017-64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: To my knowledge this is not interrupting any of my installs. It is like its permanently stuck in the install queue.